# Get the Attribute ID of Button in Bootstrap & AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a Button in Bootstrap and assigning an attribute to it. Upon clicking the button, I wish to get the attribute value in the function. However, when I pass $element.currentTarget to function, I a getting undefined value in the function. Please let me know what is wrong with my approach. Below is the code

```
<div >
<a class="btn btn-info btn-circle text-uppercase" href="#" id="reply" ng-click="addReply($element.currentTarget)" data-id = "{{ comment.comment }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Reply</a>
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-circle text-uppercase" data-toggle="collapse" href="#replyOne" aria-expanded="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> 2 comments</a>
</div>

$scope.addReply = function(item) {  
    var id = angular.element(item).data('id');
    alert(id);      
};
```

Comment: Do you want to get data-id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be using angular directives instead.

```
myApp.directive('btnAttrClick', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        alert(attr.dataId);
      })
    }
  }
})
```

and your button:

```
<button btn-attr-click data-id="{{ comment.comment }}">Reply</button>
```

I didn't test the code, but you get the gist - directives is what makes angular awesome - learn 'em, love 'em

Comment: Thanks Tony, this worked. Also, I have started to study the directives in detail. Thanks again ! ! ! :)

Comment: @user3930118 - glad it worked - angular is awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$scope.addReply = function doStuff(item){
    var id = item.attributes['data-id'].value;
    alert(id);
}
```